# How to communicate between two classes in c#?

Tags: c#

I have two classes `A` and `B`. Class `A` has an instance of class `B`. Class `A` has a list of Class `Foo` with attributes `Id` and `Name` which is dynamic. As the `Run` method of class `B` is called, the local variable `id` in class `B` is calculated. Suppose the value of `id` is 2, I need to search `dynamicList` and get "Two" back.

> The `dynamicList` can be updated by an event.

```
class Foo()
{
    public Foo(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public A()
    {
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(1, "One"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(2, "Two"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(3, "Three"));

        b = B();
        b.Run();
    }
    public List<Foo> dynamicList = new List<Foo>();
}

class B 
{
    public void Run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int id;
            string name;

            // an event appended this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(4, "Four"));
            // an event appended this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(5, "Five"));


            // some code goes here that gets the value of id 4
            id = 4;

            // I need to convert the value of '4' to 'Four'
        }
    }
}
```

> I have two classes `A` and `B`. Class `A` has an instance of class
>   `B`. Class `A` has a list of Class `Foo` with attributes `Id` and
>   `Name` which is dynamic. As the `Run` method of class `B` is called,
>   the local variable `id` in class `B` is calculated. Suppose the value
>   of `id` is 2, I need to search `dynamicList` and get "Two" back.
>
> ```
> class Foo()
> {
>   public Foo(int id, string name)
>   {
>       this.Id = id;
>       this.Name = name;
>   }
>   public int Id { get; set; }
>   public string Name { get; set; }
> }
>
> class A
> {
>   public A()
>   {
>       this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(1, "One"));
>       this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(2, "Two"));
>       this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(3, "Three"));
>
>       b = B();
>       b.Run();
>   }
>     public List<Foo> dynamicList = new List<Foo>();
> }
>
> class B 
> {
>   public void Run()
>   {
>       while(true)
>       {
>           int id;
>             string name;
>
>           // some code goes here that gets the value of id 2
>           id = 2;
>
>           // I need to convert the value of '2' to 'Two'
>
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: change your method Run to accept parameter List<Foo>. then pass it when you call the method.

Comment: You should avoid to make variables public. Instead use a property for this.

Comment: Why don't you just pas the instance of A to B in the constructor of B or if only the list is needed just pass the list. Or better yet, study dependency injection, create an interface for the dynamic list service B needs, and inject the interface in the constructor of B. In A you instantiate the real implementer, and pass it to B. B does only have a dependency to the interface and not to A that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper class with values and get values from it.

```
public static class ValueHelper
{
    public static string GetValue(int i)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in `B`:

```
strint value = ValueHelper.GetValue(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this.

1 is thru parameters.

```
b.Run(dynamicList);
```

Then run your search on the method run.

```
public void Run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        // some code goes here that gets the value of id 2
        id = 2;
        var item = dynamicList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        // reference System.Linq
    }
}
```

Second would be providing a delegate on the parameter.

```
b.Run(id => dynamicList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id))
```

Make your code like this on the Run

```
public void Run(Func<int, Foo> getItem)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        // some code goes here that gets the value of id 2
        id = 2;
        var item = getItem(id);
        // reference System.Linq
    }
}
```

There are lots of other ways to do it, these are just examples on how to do it with minimal modification to your code, you can also consider design changes to further improve your process.

Comment: How do I get the value if any changes occurs in the list during when the `Run` method is running? I have edited the post again, please check for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the signature of B.Run to this:

```
public void Run(A a)
```

Then you can easily pass the list with the method call:

```
b.Run(this)
```

The list can be accessed with

```
a.dynamicList
```

Comment: How do I get the value if any changes occurs in the list during when the `Run` method is running? I have edited the post again, please check for the changes.

Comment: What if `public List<Foo> dynamicList = new List<Foo>();` is private?

Comment: This wouldn't fit in your provided example... So what is the access modifier of it now? Public or private? However you shouldn't make a variable public, you should replace it with a property with public getter and private setter. If you want to keep it private (which would be nonsense) you only can pass the pointer of the list to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make parameter of **dynamicList** to class B

```
public class Foo()
{
    public Foo(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    B b = null;
    public A()
    {
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(1, "One"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(2, "Two"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(3, "Three"));

        b =new B();
        b.Run(dynamicList);
    }
    public List<Foo> dynamicList = new List<Foo>();
}

public class B 
{

    public void Run(List<Foo> DynamicList)
    {
        Foo foo = null;
        while(true)
        {
            foo = DynamicList[0];
            int id = foo.Id;
            string name = foo.Name;

            //here you can add your logic..
            // it may be foreach loop or something else..
            //and iterate all List in DynamicList

            // some code goes here that gets the value of id 2
            id = 2;

            // I need to convert the value of '2' to 'Two'

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the value if any changes occurs in the list during when the `Run` method is running? I have edited the post again, please check for the changes.

Comment: So you have to make run method static, instead of any class..  and the you call it, or you can call run method every time when ever you change or update List..

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the parameter List<Foo> dynamicList in Run method and pass the List from the caller class constructor A().
class Foo()
{
    public Foo(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public A()
    {
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(1, "One"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(2, "Two"));
        this.dynamicList.Add(new Foo(3, "Three"));

        b = B();
        b.Run(dynamicList);
    }
    public List<Foo> dynamicList = new List<Foo>();
}

class B 
{
            public void Run(List<Foo> dynamicList)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int id;
            string name;

            var data= dynamicList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==2);
            id=data.Id;
            //id = 2;
            var two=  dynamicList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==2).Select(x=>x.Name);
            // I need to convert the value of '2' to 'Two'

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are expecting.